Blazor server displaying data through a async Task<string> task not displaying string
I am making a Roster with all different types of employees. I am using a table to display this data where i used to have it so it was displaing the first name of the employees which were the own individual accounts. I instead want to have the roster contain the Id of the employee accounts so i am not relying on the first name only incase there a double ups in names. Unless there is a way to have the ApplicationUser data type in my sql database, I have to have the Id of the employee and then when i want to display the roster, get the first name of employee by the Id. However when i run this code i dont get the first name i get this instead:
Here is the code I have tried so far to display the data:
Image of the code running result
@foreach (var day in context.DayOfWeek)
{
    
    <tr>
        <th>@day.Day</th>
        <th>@day.OpenTime</th>
        <th>@day.CloseTime</th>
        <th>@GetNameFromIdAsync(day.Manager1)</th>
        <th>@GetNameFromIdAsync(day.Manager2)</th>
        <th>@GetNameFromIdAsync(day.Kitchen1)</th>
        <th>@GetNameFromIdAsync(day.Kitchen2)</th>
        <th>@GetNameFromIdAsync(day.Kitchen3)</th>
        <th>@GetNameFromIdAsync(day.Driver1)</th>
        <th>@GetNameFromIdAsync(day.Driver2)</th>
        <th>@GetNameFromIdAsync(day.Driver3)</th>
        <AuthorizeView Roles="Administrator">
            <th><a href="@($"rosterdays/edit?id={day.Id}")"><button class="btn-warning">Edit</button></a></th>
            <th><a href="@($"rosterdays/delete?id={day.Id}")"><button class="btn-danger">Delete</button></a></th>
        </AuthorizeView>


    </tr>
}

Here is the async task i created:
private async Task<string> GetNameFromIdAsync(string id)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

    if(user != null && user.FirstName != null)
    {
        return user.FirstName;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }

}

I am new to blazor and sql so if there is a way i can have ApplicationUser datatype in the database or link the a asp.net user row to column in a seperate table that would be great.

Change @GetNameFromIdAsync(day.Manager1) to @( await GetNameFromIdAsync(day.Manager1) )

BTW, your approach will mean invoking UserManager.FindByIdAsync 8 times for each day-of-the-week (presumably 7) for 56 separate query invocations which will be inefficient. I recommend you look into how you can reduce it down to a single query that loads all required data all-at-once.

You are not seeing result, as you do not get it correctly:
You defined asynchronous method:
private async Task<string> GetNameFromIdAsync(string id)

which does not provide result immediately, you have to await it.
To correctly call the method and get it result you need to use await:
<th>@await GetNameFromIdAsync(day.Manager1)</th>

Moreover, you are hammering you DB with tons of queries. You could optimize it a little: you should have table Users on your database context, so using that we can write our own query to fetch needed data:
var ids = // Create array with IDs to find;
var names = await _context.Users
    .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
    // Create dictionary, to later easily get name by ID.
    .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Id, x => x.FirstName);

This way, you send one query, Where limits result to just a few users you are looking for and ToDictionaryAsync specifies to fetch just needed data.
